# How to accept a integer value in HTML form and save it in a php variable

Tags: php, html

This is the code i have written

```
<HTML>
<TITLE> "Student Details" </TITLE>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
STUDENT NAME:<input type="text" name="sname">

<?php
class student
{
    public static $name="";
    public static $sclass=0;
    //settype($sclass , "integer");
}
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    student::$name=$_POST['sname'];
    student::$name=trim(student::$name);
    if(!empty(student::$name))
    {
        if(student::$name != "GOUTAM")
   {
     echo "WRONG NAME ENTERED";
   }
    }
   else
   {
    "NAME IS EMPTY";
   }
}
?>
<br>
STUDENT CLASS:<input type="text" name="sclass">
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="post")
 {

student::$sclass=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'sclass',FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    if(empty(student::$sclass))
     {
        echo  " CLASS IS EMPTY";
     }
     if(student::$sclass != 10)
     {
        echo "WRONG CLASS ENTERED";
     }
 }
 ?>
 <br>
<input type="submit"><br>
<?php echo student::$name;?>
<br>
<?php echo student::$sclass;?>
<br>
<input type="reset" name="RESET"><br> 

<?php
var_dump(student::$name);
var_dump(student::$sclass);
?>
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

in this program, im accepting a students name and his class, then im comparing it with some constants which will return some values based on the conditions.

BUT WHEN I RUN THIS CODE and enter a class for example 10 the value of $sclass doesnt change and it remains 0.

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="post")
```

should be

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
```

because `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` always contains an UPPER CASE value. Something else I'd like to suggest is to move the int code inside the first if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

you should write

```
FILTER_VAR($_POST['sclass'],FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
student::$sclass=$_POST['sclass'];
```

then you should do

Answer (score 0):

Change `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="post")` line to

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
```

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` this variable return upper case `POST`. That's why that condition block is not executed.